# Code to Parse dollars and cents?

Tags: javascript, parsing

I've written code to parse dollars and cents entered by the user.  The value returned is the total number of cents.

For example:

```
f('$1.50') = 150

f('1.5') = 150

f('0') = 0

f('1000') = 1000

f('$12,500.00') = 12500000

functions.GetTotalCents = function (dollarsAndCentsString) {
    // Cast the value passed in to a string in case a number was passed in.
    dollarsAndCentsString = dollarsAndCentsString.toString();
    // First, discard the '$' glyph, if it was passed in.
    if (dollarsAndCentsString.split('$').length == 2)
        dollarsAndCentsString = dollarsAndCentsString.split('$')[1];
    // If the user delimmited the groups of digits with commas, remove them.
    dollarsAndCentsString = dollarsAndCentsString.replace(/,/g, '');
    // Next, divide the resulting string in to dollars and cents.
    var hasDecimal = (dollarsAndCentsString.split('.')).length == 2;
    var dollarsString, centsString;
    dollarsString = dollarsAndCentsString.split('.')[0];
    var centsString = hasDecimal ? dollarsAndCentsString.split('.')[1] : '0';
    var dollars = parseInt(dollarsString, 10);
    var cents;
    if (centsString.length == 1)
        cents = parseInt(centsString, 10) * 10;
    else cents = parseInt(centsString, 10);
    if (cents > 99 || isNaN(cents) || isNaN(dollars) || !isFinite(dollars) || !isFinite(cents))
        return 0;
    var totalCents = dollars * 100 + cents;
    return totalCents;
};
```

Anyone care to critique my code?

Answer (score 10):

Wouldn't it be simpler to:

- strip out any '$' and ',' characters;
- convert to a real number;
- multiply by 100;
- take the integer part.

You can probably do that in one line (my Javascript is a bit rusty):

```
return Math.round(100 * parseFloat(dollarsAndCentsString.replace(/[$,]/g, '')));
```

Having said that, I think your f('1000') example is probably wrong: my intuition says I should interpret '1000' as dollars, not cents.

Comment: I'll consider your ideas.  For what it's worth, the reason that I consider the dollars and cents separately as real numbers is to avoid floating point arithmetic round-off errors.  Perhaps they are not relevant in this context. 0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004.

Comment: And you're right f('1000') should be 10000.